# Rviz ROS master incorrect ip address

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to run rviz in ubuntu 18.04

When running rviz, it says it's waiting for ROS master.

rviz: Waiting for master Could not contact ROS master at [http://192.168.31.200:11311], retrying...

But the ROS master is http://192.168.31.134:11311

Any assistance is appreciated

Edit:
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.31.134:11311
my ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME are commented out in bashrc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371373/rviz-ros-master-incorrect-ip-address/) by [BobbyDeity](https://answers.ros.org/users/69634/bobbydeity/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-02-09**:
In the terminal where you are running `rviz`, it would really help to know the values of the environment variables `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP` and/or `ROS_HOSTNAME`. Please edit your question and provide this information. You could run `env | grep -e "ROS_[M,I,H]"`

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-02-09**:
Also, if you want to do a bit of debugging while waiting for an answer, the value of `ROS_MASTER_URI` should be `http://192.168.31.134:11311` (if that is where your master is running, as stated in the original question). The value for `ROS_IP` should be the IP address of the terminal where you are trying to run `rviz` (maybe 192.168.31.200). `ROS_HOSTNAME` should be unset.

More info here:

- http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables
- http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

**Comment by [BobbyDeity](https://answers.ros.org/users/69634/bobbydeity/) on 2021-02-09**:
ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME are commented out in bashrc as

```
#export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.13.184
#export ROS_IP=192.168.31.134
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it, forgot to change the ROS_MASTER_URI ip to the current ip of 192.168.31.134

---

Originally posted by [BobbyDeity](https://answers.ros.org/users/69634/bobbydeity/) with karma: 26 on 2021-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1